# Getting product price including addons - WooCommerce/WooCommerce Product Addons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I am having trouble getting product prices that include price alterations from addons while using the WooCommerce Product Addons extension.

In attempt to change prices based on user role, I use a function that utilizes the “woocommerce_product_get_price” hook. In the function I grab the product price by using:

```
$product->get_regular_price();
```

But this only grabs the original price and doesn't include cost changes from product addons. Therefore prices on the cart and checkout pages are wrong if a product was added with price-altering addons.

What can I use instead of `get_regular_price()` to get price of products after addon expenses are factored in?

The function should probably look something like this:

```
function alter_price_by_user_role($price, $product) {

    //get original price
    $price = $product->get_regular_price();

    //get current user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    //if is custom role
    if( in_array('custom_role', $current_user->roles)){

        //if is cart or checkout, alter price including addons. if not, just alter base price. 
        if(is_cart() || is_checkout()){

            $totalPrice = $price + GET_ADDON_COSTS; //<----------------------how?
            $price = $totalPrice * .9; 

        }
        else{   

            //alter base prices 
            $price *= .9;

        }
    }
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'alter_price_by_user_role', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Product add-ons give selectable options to customer to customize a product (and the price of this product) that is added to cart… So you can't get that outside cart items or order items…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec ok thank you. Is there a way to access product current cart price then? So its pulling from the price it is in cart rather then it's base price. That way it would include the addon costs. Something like if(is_cart()){ $price = *get_product_cart_price*; } Perhaps like referencing cart_item instead of product?

Comment: Cart item is something live so forget it… The way could be Order items, but for the same product you can have different options, so different prices… Also if a coupon is applied, prices will change. So this seems like a nightmare, and product options add-on is not maid to be referenced… Instead variable products can be referenced as they have one variation for each possible combination…

Comment: Ah ok. Well thanks anyway for the info.